# Memory-efficient Benjamini-Hochberg FDR correction using numpy/h5py

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to calculate a set of FDR-corrected p-values using Benjamini & Hochberg's method. However, the vector I am trying to run this on contains over 10 billion values.

Given the amount of data the normal [method from statsmodel's](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/4b55fa4871cf3f1dbd2e30bfe00d80df87d4b340/statsmodels/stats/multitest.py#L263) multicomp module quickly runs out of memory. Looking at the source code of that function it seems that it creates multiple vectors with length 10 billion in memory, which is obviously not going to work, even on a machine with 100GB of RAM.

Is there a way to do this, ideally without having to keep the entire vector in memory? In particular I am wondering if it would be possible to re-implement BH in a way that allows it to run on-disk using h5py data structures.

Or any other suggestions?

Comment: just out of curiosity: What are the 10 billion p-values? I don't think there is a reason to use FDR correction like BH, I guess, with 10 billion values you can just use large number asymptotics directly. Even if you look only at the smallest 1% you still have 100 Million.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anybody else stumbles across this:

The way I solved this was to first extract all p-values that had a chance of passing the FDR correction threshold (I used 1e-5). Memory-consumption was not an issue for this, since I could just iterate through the list of p-values on disk.

This gave me a set of the ~400k lowest p-values. I then manually applied the BH procedure to these p-values, but inserted the original number of tests into the formula. Since BH is a step-up procedure, this is (as far as I know) equivalent to applying BH to the whole vector, without requiring me to sort 10 billion values.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion around whether the procedure is "step-up" (as Wikipedia labels it) or "step-down" (as Benjamini & Hochberg, 1995, label it). Either way, you're interested in the *largest* p-value which passes your test, so your heuristic seems reasonable, assuming that you start with the largest (least significant) p-value among those surviving thresholding).

Comment: Hi Nils, could you show how did you implemented BH? I have [the same problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/77399/computing-adjusted-p-values-in-batches) and couldn't solve it

Comment: It's been a bit too long to remember the details, but I believe I just applied the formula described here, setting $m$ to the original number of tests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Benjamini%E2%80%93Hochberg_procedure